# Loops Google Sheets Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The problem I'm trying to solve is the following.
I'm trying to make a loop which finds the letter "Y" and only the Y. I want to make it so if a cell  has Y in it, it will make the 4 rows to the left of it be called %NULL%. The issue is there are 2 cells per row where Y could be.

This is the code I started but don't know where to go from.

```js
function Loop1(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("EXP50");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for(var i = 1; i< data.length; i++){
      if(data[i][7-1] === "Y"){
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 3).setValue("%NULL%");
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 4).setValue("%NULL%");
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 5).setValue("%NULL%");
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 6).setValue("%NULL%");
      }
      if(data[i][13-1] === "Y") {
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 9).setValue("%NULL%");
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 10).setValue("%NULL%");
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 11).setValue("%NULL%");
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 12).setValue("%NULL%");        
      }

  }

}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `it so if a cell has Y in it, it will make the 4 rows to the left of it be called %NULL%.`. From `data[i][7-1] === "Y"`, I thought that you might chech the value of column "G". But I cannot understand `make the 4 rows to the left of it be called %NULL%`. For example, when the cell "G2" has the value of `Y`, what do you want to do? I would like to try to correctly understand your question and think of the solution.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying it more.

I want it to be if G5 is = to "Y" then C5:F5 says %NULL%
I also want this to happen if M5 is = to "Y" then I5:L5 says %NULL%

This will carry downwards throughout the spread sheet. And thanks again for the help.

Comment: Please look at the updated post this is what I came up with but the only issue I'm running into is it's only doing 1 if at a time.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to check the columns "G" and "M".
- When the cell value of the columns is "Y", you want to put `%NULL%` to the columns "C" - "F" and the columns "I" - "L" in the same row.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- I thought that `setValue` is used in the loop, the process cost will become high.

In this answer, by reducing the process cost, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the methods of `getValues` and `setValues` are used.

```js
function Loop1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("EXP50");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  data.forEach(r => {
    var [g, m] = [r[6], r[12]];
    var temp = Array(4).fill("%NULL%");
    if (g == "Y") r.splice(2, 4, ...temp);
    if (m == "Y") r.splice(8, 4, ...temp);
  });
  range.setValues(data);
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, TextFinder is used.

```js
function Loop1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("EXP50");
  var ranges = sheet.createTextFinder("Y").matchCase(true).matchEntireCell(true).findAll().reduce((ar, r) => {
    var col = r.getColumn();
    var row = r.getRow();
    if (col == 7) ar.push(`C${row}:F${row}`);
    if (col == 13) ar.push(`I${row}:L${row}`);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue("%NULL%");
}
```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createtextfinderfindtext)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `if` loop, couldn't you use something like this:

```
function Loop1(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("EXP50");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  while 1 = 1:
      if(data[i][7-1] === "Y"){
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 3).setValue("%NULL%");
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 4).setValue("%NULL%");
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 5).setValue("%NULL%");
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 6).setValue("%NULL%");
      }
      if(data[i][13-1] === "Y") {
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 9).setValue("%NULL%");
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 10).setValue("%NULL%");
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 11).setValue("%NULL%");
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 12).setValue("%NULL%");        
      }

  }

}
```

(Apologies, I do not know if this will resolve your issue.)